# Speeding up binary tree traversal with multiple processors Haskell (parallel)

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, functional-programming, multiprocessing, binary-tree

Following the examples in [Chapter 24 of "Real World Haskell"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/concurrent-and-multicore-programming.html) and [Chapter 2 of "Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html), I've managed to build the following functions for building and traversing a binary tree quickly using multiple processors.

```
import Control.Parallel (par, pseq)
import Control.DeepSeq

data Tree x = Empty | Node x (Tree x) (Tree x) deriving (Show, Read, Eq) 

-- Create instance of NFData for Tree data type (defining "normal form")
instance NFData a => NFData (Tree a) where
    rnf Empty = ()
    rnf (Node x l r) = rnf x `seq` rnf l `seq` rnf r

-- Recursive function to build a tree using multiple processors simultaneously
copyBoxPar :: Int -> Tree Int
copyBoxPar x
    | x <= 0 = Empty
    | x > 0  = force left `par` (force right `pseq` (Node x (left)(right)))
     where
     left = copyBoxPar (x-1)
     right = copyBoxPar (x-1)

-- Serial recursive function to count leaves in tree
countBoxes :: Tree x -> Int
countBoxes Empty = 0
countBoxes (Node x left right) = 1 + countBoxes (left) + countBoxes (right)
```

I can verify that using the functions above, there is a more than 2x speedup using 6 CPUs, compared to the serial equivalent.

However, I'd like to speed this up more if I can.

It seems to me that implementing a parallel version of the countBoxes function should help, but when I try to replace the definition of countBoxes with the parallel code below, I get an error "No instance for (NFData x) arising from a use of 'force'".

```
-- Parallel function to count leaves in tree
countBoxes :: Tree x -> Int
countBoxes Empty = 0
countBoxes (Node x left right) = force left `par` (force right `pseq` (1 + countBoxes (left) + countBoxes (right)))
```

Should I really expect a speedup?  How can I implement this?  Any other advice on streamlining this code would be appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a parallel version of `copyBoxPar` or `countBoxes` built with `par` and `pseq` to be faster than a serial version, especially on large trees. "the sparked computation should not be too small, otherwise the cost of forking it in parallel will be too large relative to the amount of parallelism gained" https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/lang-parallel.html After the first few forks, all of the remaining sparks are just overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parallel `countBoxes` needs an `NFData (Tree x)` instance to use `force` on the `Tree x`s `left` and `right`. You can require that one exists by adding `NFData x` to the context for the type signature for `countBoxes`.

```
-- Parallel function to count leaves in tree
countBoxes :: NFData x => Tree x -> Int
...
```

`NFData x` is enough to deduce `NFData (Tree x)` from due to your `instance NFData a => NFData (Tree a)`.

I suggest you try running this to see how it affects performance. Perhaps a parallel `countBoxes` shouldn't need to be able to `force` an entire tree ...

Comment: Thanks!  That works nicely.  As you suggested, the improvement in performance is very slight for this toy example problem: https://gist.github.com/CnrLwlss/0c0bf1940bfed59faeac The real problem I have in mind uses richer data structures in place of Integers and carries out operations more expensive than subtracting one from an integer at each node.  I will check performance for both alternatives.